# How can I define jQuery selectors dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to make a dynamic mouseover/mouseleave jQuery function.
Currently only the first element is covered by the function as shown in the attached snippet.
But I also want to make the other elements work without having to set up one jQuery function per object.

The DOMs are structured in such way that there are 1x wrapper, 1x tooltip DOM and 1x circle DOM created per element in the JSON return.

Is there are proper way to achieve this?

In advance thank you for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseover", "#id10", function() {
    $("#tooltip10").show();
  });
  $(document).on("mouseleave", "#id10", function() {
    $("#tooltip10").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#mainContent .thirdRow .column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#mainContent .LatestResults {
  color: #919191;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-45%);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointred {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF5B5B;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointblue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4B49AE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mainContent">

    <div class="thirdRow">

      <div class="resultData column">


        <div class="resultWrapper10 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="" id="tooltip10">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper18 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id18"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip18">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper21 column">
          <div class="datapointblue datapoint" id="id21"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip21">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper37 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id37"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip37">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper45 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id45"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip45">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1110 column">
          <div class="datapointred datapoint" id="id1110"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1110">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper53 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id53"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip53">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper65 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id65"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip65">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1115 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id1115"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1115">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


















<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can use class instead of id and hide/show $(this) object

Comment: In future, please reduce the example so it's **minimal**. :-) More: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this selector `[id^=id]`, `id^=id` means every id that starts with id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseover", "[id^=id]", function() {
    $(this).next("table").show();
  });
  $(document).on("mouseleave", "[id^=id]", function() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseover", "[id^=id]", function() {
    $(this).next("table").show();
  });
  $(document).on("mouseleave", "[id^=id]", function() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#mainContent .thirdRow .column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#mainContent .LatestResults {
  color: #919191;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-45%);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointred {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF5B5B;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointblue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4B49AE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mainContent">

    <div class="thirdRow">

      <div class="resultData column">


        <div class="resultWrapper10 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="" id="tooltip10">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper18 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id18"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip18">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper21 column">
          <div class="datapointblue datapoint" id="id21"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip21">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper37 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id37"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip37">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper45 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id45"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip45">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1110 column">
          <div class="datapointred datapoint" id="id1110"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1110">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper53 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id53"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip53">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper65 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id65"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip65">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1115 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id1115"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1115">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


















<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions for you:

### Still using JavaScript

Use a class on all of the elements you want the handlers to handle, not an ID. IDs are by their nature required to be unique. Within the handler, use `this` so you know which element the event targeted, and from that find the tooltip:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseover", ".datapoint", function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".tooltip").show();
  });
  $(document).on("mouseleave", ".datapoint", function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".tooltip").hide();
  });
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseover", ".datapoint", function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".tooltip").show();
  });
  $(document).on("mouseleave", ".datapoint", function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".tooltip").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#mainContent .thirdRow .column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#mainContent .LatestResults {
  color: #919191;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-45%);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointred {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF5B5B;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointblue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4B49AE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mainContent">

    <div class="thirdRow">

      <div class="resultData column">


        <div class="resultWrapper10 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="" id="tooltip10">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper18 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id18"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip18">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper21 column">
          <div class="datapointblue datapoint" id="id21"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip21">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper37 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id37"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip37">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper45 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id45"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip45">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1110 column">
          <div class="datapointred datapoint" id="id1110"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1110">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper53 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id53"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip53">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper65 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id65"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip65">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1115 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id1115"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1115">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Using CSS instead

You can use the fact that the tooltip is a sibling of the `div` that triggers it to do this with CSS:

```
.datapoint + .tooltip {
    display: none;
}
.datapoint:hover + .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Live Example:

```css
#mainContent .thirdRow .column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#mainContent .LatestResults {
  color: #919191;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-45%);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointred {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF5B5B;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointblue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4B49AE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

.datapoint + .tooltip {
    display: none;
}
.datapoint:hover + .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mainContent">

    <div class="thirdRow">

      <div class="resultData column">


        <div class="resultWrapper10 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="" id="tooltip10">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper18 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id18"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip18">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper21 column">
          <div class="datapointblue datapoint" id="id21"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip21">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper37 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id37"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip37">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper45 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id45"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip45">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1110 column">
          <div class="datapointred datapoint" id="id1110"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip1110">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper53 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id53"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip53">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper65 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id65"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip65">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1115 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id1115"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip1115">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Be sure to remove the inline `style="display:none"` on the tooltips as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code please

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("mouseover", ".datapoint", function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".tooltip").show();
        });
        $(document).on("mouseleave", ".datapoint", function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".tooltip").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use wild card on id when `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` . Catch the id to show tool tip and based upon that hide show .

```js
let $id = $("[id^=id]");
let id = '';
$('.tooltip').hide();
$id.mouseenter(function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id').split('id')[1];
  $("#tooltip" + id).show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $("#tooltip" + id).hide();
});
```

```css
#mainContent .thirdRow .column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#mainContent .LatestResults {
  color: #919191;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-45%);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointred {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF5B5B;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointblue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4B49AE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <div class="thirdRow">
      <div class="resultData column">
        <div class="resultWrapper10 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="" id="tooltip10">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper18 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id18"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip18">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper21 column">
          <div class="datapointblue datapoint" id="id21"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip21">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper37 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id37"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip37">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper45 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id45"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip45">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1110 column">
          <div class="datapointred datapoint" id="id1110"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1110">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper53 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id53"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip53">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper65 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id65"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip65">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1115 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id1115"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="display:none" id="tooltip1115">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use classes instead of ids, and you don't need javascript for that, you all you need is css

```
.tooltip{display:none}/*use this instead of the inline-styling*/

[id^="id"]:hover + [id^="tooltip"]{
  display:block;
}
```

here is the demo

```css
#mainContent .thirdRow .column {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#mainContent .LatestResults {
  color: #919191;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mainContent .resultData .tooltip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-45%);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ADADAD;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}

#mainContent .resultData {
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
}

#mainContent .datapointred {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF5B5B;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointgreen {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00DC8E;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}

#mainContent .datapointblue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #4B49AE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
}
.tooltip{display:none}
[id^="id"]:hover + [id^="tooltip"]{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mainContent">

    <div class="thirdRow">

      <div class="resultData column">


        <div class="resultWrapper10 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id10"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" style="" id="tooltip10">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper18 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id18"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip18">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper21 column">
          <div class="datapointblue datapoint" id="id21"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip21">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper37 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id37"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip37">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper45 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id45"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip45">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1110 column">
          <div class="datapointred datapoint" id="id1110"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip1110">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper53 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id53"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip53">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper65 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id65"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip65">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="resultWrapper1115 column">
          <div class="datapointgreen datapoint" id="id1115"></div>
          <table class="tooltip" id="tooltip1115">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Hometeam</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>hometeam</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2 (1)</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Venue</td>
                <td>Emirates</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of id we can use class . Using this (self reference operator ) we can get the child element having class tooltip  by function find() which  look into  child elements .

```js
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".datapoint", function() {
    $(this).find(".tooltip").show();
  });
  $(document).on("mouseleave", ".datapoint", function() {
    $(this).find(".tooltip").hide();
  });
```

Comment: can u give some explanation of your code? it will help for someone new.

Comment: yeah sure. ! sorry as it was my very first answer here. well thanks for the suggestion   :)